# How is the vav extra?

Tags: words, parashas-yisro, maseches-kesubos

In Ketubot, 103a the text discusses what the "et" words include in the phrase
כַּבֵּ֥ד אֶת־אָבִ֖יךָ וְאֶת־אִמֶּ֑ךָ

Each et refers to another spouse of the parent so the non-biological step parent is included.

The gemara then explains what it calls an extra vav:
וָיו יְתֵירָה לְרַבּוֹת אֶת אָחִיךָ הַגָּדוֹל

The extra vav is to include your older brother.

Rashi explains that the vav referred to is דואת אמך the vav on the "et" in v'et imecha.

To say that the vav is extra indicates that without it, the text would be sufficient. In fact, the Schottenstein posits that the phrase could have been כַּבֵּ֥ד אָבִ֖יךָ אִמֶּ֑ךָ (Honor your father, your mother).

But without a conjunction, the phrase is not clear. What does "honor your father, your mother" mean? Are there other examples where a verb is applied across items that are not connected by a conjunction (especially after a tzivui verb)?

How is the vav superfluous?

Comment: שֶׁ֥מֶשׁ יָרֵ֖חַ עָ֣מַד זְבֻ֑לָה and רְאוּבֵ֣ן שִׁמְע֔וֹן לֵוִ֖י וִיהוּדָֽה (Radak's favorite examples of missing 'implied' vav)

Comment: The list of names has a comma before the last item on the list (like the father and mother) and the Chabakuk list has two items as the subject, not object of the verb, but is closer and begs the question of whether every vav that joins items in a list is necessarily "extra" and subject to explication.

Comment: Search radak on tanach for שמש ירח to find dozens of examples. It's not like את is actually extra either, recall. It's a grammatical word that denotes the direct object (or so). Extra here doesn't mean completely pointless.

Comment: I found 3 shemesh Vyare'ach (and if I understood the michat shai on the Chabakuk example, that might help distinguish the cases). The Radak in Ber 9:3 is speaking of a different construction, and he still explains why there is a lack of a vav because the lack changes the meaning. It might be that the notion of "יְתֵירָה " needs to be explained or what a וי"ו השמוש is and does that makes it available for explication or is exclusively necessary for the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: On the simplest level (perhaps the best way to view Rashi) one’s Mother and Father would be presumed to be Husband and Wife. The Torah view is that Husband and Wife are one, literally. In that context, the addition of the letter Vav would seem to be superfluous and indicative of a Father who is not the biological parent of the offspring.

Comment: In my opinion, the Gemmorah works the other way - it does not infer FROM the text, it finds a SUPPORT in it. In other words, the sages knew, that the older brother must be honored, but where's the source, where's the hint? It's in *the possibility* of calling this vav an extra. Otherwise, it should have learned every vav in the Torah, such as "בראשית ברא א' את השמים ואת הארץ"

Comment: @AlBerko that final point just begs the question - if we don't see every vav in an analogous use as extra, why see this one as extra (and the gemara uses the word yeteira so it isn't just that we learn from a letter, but from an "extra" letter). If every et can be open for explication (Shimon ha'Amsoni, Pes 22a) then it isn't just that "some" are. If only some vavin are available, why them?

Comment: @rosends In my understanding, rabbis frequently use "as if" to explain the support, like in אל תקרא, אלא. In other words, certainly, vav is not extra, this is plainly ridiculous, but we *might see it as if* it was extra with a little effort. Like in the Halachic discussion of מאה ברכות we might read it as "מאה" instead of "מה".